# linker cannot find reference to .a library passed as argument to gcc

Tags: c, gcc, linker, makefile

I'm following the "Learn C the Hard Way" ebook(?), and reached [exercise 32](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex32.html).

It uses a previously developed project structure, where tests link to the built library. However, when I run `make test`, I get "undefined reference to X", where X is every function defined in my library's header.

`twoll_tests.c` is my test file, `libds` is the library. See project tree at the bottom of this question.

The compilation line for the tests is this:

```
cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG -std=c11 build/libds.a tests/twoll_tests.c -o tests/twoll_tests
```

Makefile contents:

```
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG -std=c11 $(OPTFLAGS)
LIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)
PREFIX?=/usr/local

SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.c src/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

TEST_SRC=$(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
TESTS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(TEST_SRC))

TARGET=build/libds.a
SO_TARGET=$(patsubst %.a,%.so,$(TARGET))

# The Target Build
all: $(TARGET) $(SO_TARGET)

dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Isrc -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
dev: all

$(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $(OBJECTS)
    ranlib $@

$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

build:
    @mkdir -p build
    @mkdir -p bin

# The Unit Tests
.PHONY: test
test: CFLAGS += $(TARGET)
test: $(TESTS)
    sh ./tests/runtests.sh

valgrind:
    VALGRIND="valgrind --log-file=/tmp/valgrind-%p.log" $(MAKE)

# The Cleaner
clean:
    rm -rf build $(OBJECTS) $(TESTS)
    rm -f tests/tests.log
    find . -name "*.gc*" -exec rm {} \;
    rm -rf `find . -name "*.dSYM" -print`

# The Install
install: all
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/

# The Checker
BADFUNCS='[^_.>a-zA-Z0-9](str(n?cpy|n?cat|xfrm|n?dup|str|pbrk|tok|_)|stpn?cpy|a?sn?printf|byte_)'
check:
    @echo Files with potentially dangerous functions.
    @egrep $(BADFUNCS) $(SOURCES) || true
```

And finally, the project tree:

```
.
├── bin
├── build
│   ├── libds.a
│   └── libds.so
├── LICENSE
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── libds
│       ├── twoll.c
│       ├── twoll.h
│       └── twoll.o
└── tests
    ├── runtests.sh
    ├── tester.h
    ├── tests.log
    └── twoll_tests.c
```

**EDIT:** Here's the full output of `make test`:

```
kroltan@kroltan ~/Projects/learncthehardway/ex32 $ make all
cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -std=c11  -fPIC   -c -o src/libds/twoll.o src/libds/twoll.c
ar rcs build/libds.a src/libds/twoll.o
ranlib build/libds.a
cc -shared -o build/libds.so src/libds/twoll.o
kroltan@kroltan ~/Projects/learncthehardway/ex32 $ make test
cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG -std=c11  build/libds.a    tests/twoll_tests.c   -o tests/twoll_tests
/tmp/ccnOW9OX.o: In function `twoll_new_test':
/home/kroltan/Projects/learncthehardway/ex32/tests/twoll_tests.c:8: undefined reference to `twoll_new'
/tmp/ccnOW9OX.o: In function `twoll_del_test':
/home/kroltan/Projects/learncthehardway/ex32/tests/twoll_tests.c:13: undefined reference to `twoll_new'
/home/kroltan/Projects/learncthehardway/ex32/tests/twoll_tests.c:13: undefined reference to `twoll_del'
/tmp/ccnOW9OX.o: In function `twoll_push_pop_test':
/home/kroltan/Projects/learncthehardway/ex32/tests/twoll_tests.c:18: undefined reference to `twoll_new'
/home/kroltan/Projects/learncthehardway/ex32/tests/twoll_tests.c:18: undefined reference to `twoll_push'
/home/kroltan/Projects/learncthehardway/ex32/tests/twoll_tests.c:18: undefined reference to `twoll_push'
/home/kroltan/Projects/learncthehardway/ex32/tests/twoll_tests.c:18: undefined reference to `twoll_push'
/home/kroltan/Projects/learncthehardway/ex32/tests/twoll_tests.c:18: undefined reference to `twoll_pop'
/home/kroltan/Projects/learncthehardway/ex32/tests/twoll_tests.c:18: undefined reference to `twoll_pop'
/home/kroltan/Projects/learncthehardway/ex32/tests/twoll_tests.c:18: undefined reference to `twoll_pop'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tests/twoll_tests] Error 1
```

Comment: Looks like your make rule builds the library first. can you provide your full make output?

Comment: @UmamaheshP Edited question.

Comment: The make output indicates the library was not built. Did you run make with all option i.e. "make all"?.

Comment: @UmamaheshP That's just the `make test` output, but the library was already built before. (e.g. I ran  `make all; make test`) I'll edit the question in under a minute.

Comment: @UmamaheshP Edited, please see again.

Comment: If you see the library libds.a in builds dir,try this command.  cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG -std=c11  tests/twoll_tests.c   -o tests/twoll_tests -L builds -lds

Comment: Were you able to resolve the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That worked, @UmamaheshP. If you would post that as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Happy to know that it worked. But I think a full library path should also work. I have not looked into that yet. Will add an answer later if required. Thanks.

Comment: the key factor in making it work is that referenced libraries must be listed last in the gcc link step.   This is because gcc processes the line from left to right and since the library was listed before the object files, when the library was listed, there were no unresolved references.  Moving the library reference to after the object files results in their being unresolved references that the library will resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [@unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35799380/1045510) and [@Umamahesh P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35799138/linker-cannot-find-reference-to-a-library-passed-as-argument-to-gcc?noredirect=1#comment59287629_35799138), it was found that the library must be added after the target when invoking the compiler. After some extra searching around the internet, I've found that the correct Make variable for libraries is actually `LDLIBS`, not `LIBS` as was given on the book. I've changed the variable usage, and added the following assignment to my `test` target:

```
test: LDLIBS += $(TARGET)
```

With just that, linking is successful.

Answer (score 3):

This part of the compiler invocation:

```
build/libds.a    tests/twoll_tests.c
```

is bad; you always want the libraries *after* the source files. Think of it like this:

1. Source file *creates* references to symbols
2. Libraries *resolve* references to symbols

You can't resolve something *before* it's been created, so the libraries should go last.

Comment: Note that this changed: I distincly recall that in older versions of gcc you where able to put libraries first and gcc would implicitly permutate the operand order.

Comment: How can I change that within the makefile? It would seem to me that line 34 is already appending the `.a` to the end of CFLAGS, however it seems that internally Make does something like `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(the target)`. How would I tell it to put the library after the target?